# replacing regular expression not working in mysql and mariadb

Tags: mysql, regex, replace, mariadb

I want to replace the string in mysql using regular expression. For this, I am using REGEXP_REPLACE but it is not giving me the desired result.

I am trying to replace `&breakUp=Mumbai;city,Puma;brand&` to `&breakUp=Mumbai;city,Puma;brand,Delhi;State&` but regexp replace not giving me the desired result.

I am using the following sql query:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('&breakUp=Mumbai;city,Puma;brand&','&breakUp=([\w;,]*)&','&breakUp=$1,Delhi;State&');
```

But it is giving me the following result:

```
&breakUp=Mumbai;city,Puma;brand&
```

The same regular expressions are working fine in other places except sql.
How to resolve this in mysql and mariadb?

Comment: Are you sure the replacement backreference syntax is `$1`? Try `\\1` in the replacement. And `[^&]*` instead of `[\w;,]*`

Comment: As per your @WiktorStribiżew 's comment, please find the [working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6325a3dc9c05bbd1648b7f46689c1f8)

Comment: @Arulkumar Ok, so, that is MySQL 8, and `$1` works. Good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\w` is not valid. You can use `[[:alnum:]]` or `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `\w`:

**Solution on MySQL:**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('&breakUp=Mumbai;city,Puma;brand&','&breakUp=([[[:alnum:]];,]*)&','&breakUp=$1,Delhi;State&');
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4bd0839745c211490afeeda27046445)

**Solution on MariaDB:**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('&breakUp=Mumbai;city,Puma;brand&','&breakUp=([[:alnum:];,]*)&','&breakUp=\\1,Delhi;State&');
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=2028097262986991df5fd20c23573283)

Comment: Thanks. How to do the same in MariaDB?